# Dependency Injection with 2 constructors

Tags: c#-4.0, dependency-injection, unity-container

Is it possible to use Dependency Injection in a class which has 2 constructors?

for example, assume I have the next interface:

```
    public interface ILogger
    {
        void Log(LogLevel level, string message, string CallerID);
    }
```

and it's implementation:

```
internal class NLogger : ILogger
{
    private static NLog.Logger _logger;

    public NLogger()
    {
        _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    }

    public NLogger(ISomeService srv): this()
    {
        srv.doSomthing();
    }

    public void Log(LogLevel level, string message, string CallerID)
    {
        //implementation
    }
}
```

I want to inject `ISomeService` just in case it exists in my DI container and in case it doesn't exists - use the empty constructor and continue working without `ISomeService`.

Is it possible? if not, do you have a recommendation how to implement something similar?

Comment: Having multiple constructors [is an anti-pattern](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97). Please don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity by default will choose the constructor with the most parameters.  If you want it to use a certain constructor when you're register the mapping, you can use InjectionConstructor.

```
// Using default constructor
this.unityContainer.RegisterType<ILogger, NLogger>(new InjectionConstructor());

// Using ISomeService constructor
this.unityContainer.RegisterType<ILogger, NLogger>(new InjectionConstructor(new ResolvedParameter<ISomeService>()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, most IoC containers will pick the most greedy constructor that it can satisfy. That means that if you have `ISomeService` registered, it will pick that constructor, otherwise it will fall back to the default constructor.

Comment: I assumed this would be the case but I tried to remove `ISomeService` registration and when I resolving ILogger I'm getting an exception

Comment: @Ofir: That's because Unity is a 'group 2' container, as explained in [this article](http://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97). Group 2 is the most useless group to be in for a container.

Comment: Thanks, after I read your link I saw that `[OptionalDependency]` can solve my issue. I didn't know this feature. Thanks